# Capitalize first letter of array with strings

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capitalize first letter of array with strings, I add my method to `String` but it's only returning the first letter capitalized not the full sentence. So it should be "Hi There How Are You?"

```js
const str = "Hi there how are you?";

String.prototype.toJadenCase = function(st) {
  let arr = st.split(" ");
  arr.forEach(function(ele, index) {
    arr[index] = ele.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  });
  return arr;
};

console.log(String.prototype.toJadenCase("Hi there how are you"));
```

Returns array of only first letter not full word ["H", "T", "H", "A", "Y"]

Comment: You have to change `arr[index][0] = ele.charAt(0).toUpperCase();` Currently you are replacing the whole string at `index` position in the array. Rather only replace the first letter

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Comment: This can also be donde using `string.replace()`. Something like this: `const toJadenCase = (str) => str.replace(/\s./g, m => m.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add remaining part of string as well

```js
const str = "Hi there how are you?";

String.prototype.toJadenCase = function (st) {
    let arr = st.split(" ");
    arr.forEach(function(ele, index) {
        arr[index] = ele.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ele.substr(1)
    });
    return arr;
};

console.log(String.prototype.toJadenCase("Hi there how are you"));
```

It's not a good practice to add methods on `Prototype` you can simply write a function and use it

```js
const str = "Hi there how are you?";

const changeFirstChar = (str) => str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substr(1)

const toJadenCase = function(st) {
  let arr = st.split(" ");
  return arr.map(e => changeFirstChar(e))
};

console.log(toJadenCase("Hi there how are you"));

//if you need output as string
console.log(toJadenCase("Hi there how are you").join(' '));
```